# Publish additional cursors within an observer

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a document that looks like this.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  orders: [ObjectId, ObjectId]
}
```

A lookup on those orders will yield something like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  products: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ObjectId]
}
```

Now my publication will find and observe the parent `Meteor.users`.

```
Meteor.publish(function () {
  let handle = Meteor.users.find(this.userId).observe({
    added: doc => {
      // publish all orders
      // publish all products within that order
    },
    changed: doc => { /** same as above */ }
  });
  this.ready();
  this.onStop(() => handle.stop());
});
```

When any of these change, I want to modify the top-level document and publish it. That is to say:

```
this.changed('user', doc._id, publishRelations(doc));
```

Is this possible with meteor?

Comment: Possible use for this package https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Comment: Not exactly what I am after because I want to mutate the document as well (see last line). That's the only real reason that package isn't what I am after

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with peerlibrary:reactive-publish.  You just wrap the cursors you want to publish in an autorun within your publication. It should be re-run anytime one of the reactive dependencies (in this case, the three cursors) changes:

```
Meteor.publish("userOrders", function() {
   var self = this;
   self.autorun(function() {
      var productIds = [];

      // get logged in user
      var userCursor = Meteor.users.find(self.userId);

      //  get orders belonging to logged in user
      var ordersCursor = Orders.find({userId: self.userId});


      // create array of product Ids from user's orders  
      // You could probably make this better by omitting duplicates  
      ordersCursor.forEach(function(doc, index) {
        _.each(doc.products, function(productId) {
           productIds.push(productId);
         });
      });

      // get products in array
      var productsCursor = Products.find({ _id: { $in : productIds } });

      // return array of cursors
      return [
         userCursor,
         ordersCursor,
         productsCursor
      ];

   });

});
```